# how to tell dotnet core version 7 UserManager to update it's security certificate to a new key

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, http-put, usermanager

DotNet CORE V7 has a UserManager which is a part of the Microsoft Identity Framework.
When I attempt process an Http PUT request in my backend server, I am able to provide all the data that needs to be changed.
However, writing the updates back goes through the UserManager and I get errors stating that the Security Certificate can't be null. This certificate is internal to UserManager.
It's a seemingly random string of 32 characters, but I believe it has to be generated by UserManager itself.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

I attempted to fill in the string with a Guid converted to a string without the dashes or curly braces.  This didn't work.
I've searched for UserManager functions I might use; some were recommended, but when I tried to use them, they didn't compile.